# Is this an issue with the law of the excluded middle, or an issue with the proof?

Tags: number-theory

Part of a proof requiring you to prove that if $x^2$ is odd then $x$ is odd (given that $x \in \mathbb{N}$). It is my understanding that the contrapositive is used for this as follows.

$x=2n, n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\Rightarrow x^2 = 4n^2$

$\Rightarrow x^2$ is even

Then using the contrapositive:

$\Rightarrow \lnot Even(x^2) \rightarrow \lnot Even(x)$

Now the Law of the excluded middle:

$\Rightarrow Odd(x^2) \rightarrow Odd(x)$

So reasonably straight forward. However, my issue with this is whilst $x^2$ is even, it is even more strictly defined as a multiple of $4$. So in the contrapositive sense it doesn't feel right that it can be any even number. So what happens if that said number is 6? Not strictly divisible by 4 but still even. This is a bit difficult because this proof's conclusion is actually correct and any squared integer is either divible by 4 or odd. But that was found through exhaustion in a different way. Using the law of the excluded middle after saying that it wasn't just any even number seems spurious.

Could someone please clarify if I am right with reservation about this? If not, please explain (without just saying it is contrapositive, therefore). I feel like there should be a continuing connection between the definition of what type of even and what can be deduced from that.

Comment: What is the definition of $\operatorname{Odd}(n)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen 'is even' and 'is odd', I think

Comment: Any number divisible by $4$ is even. Every even square is divisible by $4$. The first of these is relevant to the proof, the second is not.

Comment: $x^2\neq6$ as you've just proven it is $4\,|\,x^2$?? In a sense, you seem to be asking something along the lines of truth of $P\implies Q$ when $P$ is false. If that is the case, then note $\lnot P\implies(P\implies Q)$

Comment: Correct, $Odd(n)$ means $n$ is odd. And the $Even(n)$ means $n$ is even.

Comment: I get what you're saying. But is anyone not seeing the subtlety of what I've said though. I know even square is divisible by 4. All I'm saying is if you get an even number not divisible by 4, like 6. Then I feel like the contrapositive shouldn't hold. Not a great example because the conclusion is true, but I feel this is an invalid proof.

Comment: I think I'm seeing your point, and I think the answer below by @NoahSchweber addresses it. The first part of the proof may establish *more than* $x^2$ being even, but it establishes that $x^2$ is even, which is what we need. If we have $p\implies (q \wedge r)$, then we have $p\implies q$, so we have $\neg q \implies \neg p$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Exactly. Thanks. Well structured in propositional logic to express the point. So if we contradict $q \land r$ we have $\lnot q \lor \lnot r$ so if $q$ represents it being even, we also don't have to show $r$, that it is also divisible by 4, to do the contrapositive properly.

Comment: ^ Yes.$$(p\implies(q\land r))\iff(\neg (q\land r) \implies \neg p)\iff(\neg q\lor\neg r) \implies \neg p)\iff((\neg q\ \implies \neg p)\land(\neg r\ \implies \neg p))$$ We only need the first statement in our proof.

Comment: Also note that $r$ is the statement $4|x^2$. I think your point of concern relates to the second statement $4\not|\,x^2\implies 2\not|\,x$. We then can say $x^2 = 6\implies 4\not|\,x^2$ which leads to $(x^2=6\implies 2\not|\,x$. But of course, $x^2\neq6$ as $x$ is an integer. We can prove any statement with a false premise. Hence $\lnot P\implies(P\implies Q)$.

Comment: Update, I am really thick haha. It's just a double use of the contrapositive. If it's not even, then it's not divisible by 4, then it's not even. *facepalm*

Comment: @AER if its not divisible by $4$ it can be even???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're in Paris, then you're in Europe. Even more particularly, you're in France. However, "if you're not in Europe, then you're not in Paris," is still a valid application of the contrapositive, even though we've "forgotten" the information about being in France.

"You're in Paris." $\longleftrightarrow  x$ is even.

"You're in Europe." $\longleftrightarrow  x^2$ is even.

"You're in France." $\longleftrightarrow  x^2$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: It's literally modus ponens but with contrapositive. I'm such an idiot...

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. It's good to grapple with these ideas. Makes them more solid for more confusing situations in the future. :)

Comment: This is some delightful exposition.

Answer (score 11):

Ignore the broader proof - do you agree with the assertion "If $x$ is divisible by $4$, then $x$ is even?" This is all that's going on. We're always allowed to "forget" information in a proof, and this has nothing to do with the excluded middle. When you conclude "$x^2$ is even," this *in no way implies* that you've concluded "$x^2$ is even *and that's the most that can be said*."

Comment: It's this forgetting of information that I find tenuous. We are concluding that $x^2$ is only some of the even numbers though. Is there an explanation why?

Comment: If you're in Paris, then you're in Europe. Even more particularly, you're in France. However, "if you're not in Europe, then you're not in Paris," is still a valid application of the contrapositive, even though we've "forgotten" the information about being in France.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I think this is the actual answer. Please submit this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to forget information in a proof. Not that I've read it, but it seems spurious. Especially in the case of the Monty Hall as an example.

Comment: @AER Too bad, it's true. (Also, what does the Monty Hall problem have to do with this?) Regardless of whether it seems spurious, it is a thing you can do. Think about it: do you understand why more powerful statements ("$a$ is divisible by $4$") imply weaker ones ("$a$ is even")? If not, why not? If so, that's why that's a valid step in a proof. Proofs are "truth-preserving;" they're not required to "conserve information" in any sense, the only requirement is that they follow rules which will never lead you from *true statements* to a *false* statement.

Comment: I'm really curious - can you articulate why you think this isn't allowed, and what role you think it plays in the Monty Hall problem?

Comment: Depends what you mean by forget. Is there any resources on this I can read? The comments on the question highlight the issue. But it's resolved in the logic mentioned there. You can forget information in a contrapositive proof if you're contradicting a set of "and" properties.

Comment: @AER By "forget," I just mean this: if you've already proved some statement $A$ (in this case, "$x$ is divisible by $4$"), and you've also proved the statement "$A\implies B$" for some $B$ (in this case, "If $x$ is divisible by $4$, then $x$ is even"), then you can conclude $B$, and in fact you can conclude this in the middle of a larger proof.

Comment: Sure, I'm being super intuitive about this. But in the Monty Hall paradox (it's more a failure of frequentism in some ways), what has happened, or how we arrive at that state is of importance.

Comment: @AER That's a different kind of information at play. This is the danger with using informal language to explain things. At its core, all this is is modus ponens: from $A$ and $A\implies B$, we can conclude $B$, *regardless of whether $B$ is enough to imply $A$*. Our proofs don't have to be "reversible."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63752/discussion-between-aer-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: We also know that $x^2\not\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, but we don't have to use that, or even mention it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a law of excluded middle that you need to prove that every integer is either even or odd.  Excluded middle applies equally to integers and reals, but not every real is even or odd.  To prove this property requires a property of integers, such as the division algorithm (divide by 2, look at remainder).

Comment: Agreed. I meant with integers. Updated question to remove this lack of clarity.

Comment: Euclid made this same mistake, so OP is in good company.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(p(x)\equiv2\mid x), (q(x)\equiv2\mid x^2), (r(x)\equiv4\mid x^2)$.

Then we have

$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(2\mid x\implies4\mid x^2)$$
$\implies$
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(2\mid x\implies(2\mid x^2\land 4\mid x^2))$$
$\implies$
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(\neg (2\mid x^2\land 4\mid x^2) \implies 2\nmid x)$$
$\implies$
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad((2\nmid x^2\lor4\nmid x^2) \implies \neg 2\nmid x)$$
$\implies$
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad((2\nmid x^2 \implies 2\nmid x)\land(4\nmid x^2 \implies 2\nmid x))$$
$\implies$
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(2\nmid x^2 \implies 2\nmid x)\land(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(4\nmid x^2 \implies 2\nmid x)$$
$\implies$
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(2\nmid x^2 \implies 2\nmid x)$$

---

Now I think your confusion comes from considering $(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(4\nmid x^2 \implies 2\nmid x)$ which is also true.

Then $(4\nmid6)\implies(x^2=6\implies4\nmid x^2)$, and so we get

$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad (x^2=6\implies4\nmid x^2\implies2\nmid x)$$

and we end up with the bizarre statement

$$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)\quad(x^2=6\implies x\text{ is odd})$$

But of course, there is no such integer whose square is $6$ (and in fact, this is a valid proof of that being the case if we also use 'the square of an odd is odd').

For all integers, $x^2=6$ is false, and we can prove anything with a false premise. In general,

$$\neg P\implies(P\implies Q)$$

is true for any statements $P$ and $Q$.